# Free flash charts which can be used for commercial use

Tags: charts

Can anyone provide me list of free flash charts which can be used for commercial purpose

free flash charts for commercial use

Comment: CSS3 would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at [FusionCharts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/).

The [licensing model](http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/product-licensing/) allows it to be used in any commercial product or personal use.

Answer (score 0):

http://amCharts.com - they have old flash version which can be used fort free.